# Overlay the div even to the scrollbar of the window

Tags: css

[image]

This [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5yar05vr/) is not overlaying to the scroll bar.

Is this even possible to overlay the `<div>` to the scroll bar too? Previous today, I thought it was not possible to  do this, but just due to my website know the workaround of it. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<div id="content">
</div>
<div id="all">
<div id="overlay"></div> 
</div>
```

css:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html,body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
#all{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#content{
    height: 200%;
}
#overlay {
    background: #000;
    margin-top: 18px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Setting overflow auto to the html,body works amazingly. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5yar05vr/2/)

If you set `overflow:visible;` then you could see that won't overlay to the scroll bar.

Comment: What's exactly the use of this? You could've set the `overflow` to `hidden` for your `body` tag if you wanted to disable scrolling.

Comment: This would be very useful to overlay the whole screen when required like pop-up...

Comment: But page will not scroll.